# Problem with CheckboxSelectMultiple and ManyToManyField with Modelform

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am quite new to Django(4months actually), I am struggling with this problem for last 2 days, I think I am making some stupid mistake. Any help or input is highly appreciated. I am using Django 1.3.

In the model I have,

```
BUSINESS_GROUP = (
    ('MNC','Multinational'),
    ('INT','International (Export/Import)'),
    ('DOM','Domestic/National'),
    ('LOC','Local'),
    ('VIR','Virtual'),
)

class BusinessGroup(models.Model):
    bgroup_type = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices = BUSINESS_GROUP, blank = True, null = True)

class Business(models.Model):
    business_group_choices = models.ManyToManyField(BusinessGroup, verbose_name= "Business Group")
```

In Form I have something like,

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BusinessForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['business_group_choices'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(choices=BUSINESS_GROUP)
```

In the view,

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = BusinessForm(request.POST, instance = business)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_business = form.save(commit=False)
        new_business.created_by = request.user
        form_values = form.cleaned_data
        new_business.save()
        assign('edit_business', request.user, new_business)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(new_business.get_absolute_url())
```

I am getting errors like,

```
"DOM" is not a valid value for a primary key.
"INT" is not a valid value for a primary key.
```

etc.

I found [source of error here in Django model source](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Python/Web-Frameworks/Django/django/forms/models.py.htm),

But not clear how to interpret and workout this problem.

**Edit:**
I tried making fields null=True and/or blank=True still I get the validation error, why?

With some changes on the whole set-up I got this new error,

```
Select a valid choice. [u'MNC', u'INT', u'DOM', u'LOC', u'VIR'] is not one of the available choices.
```

New setup:
In the model

```
class BusinessGroup(models.Model):
        bgroup_type = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Business(models.Model):
    business_group_choices = models.ManyToManyField(BusinessGroup, verbose_name= "Business Group", choices=BUSINESS_GROUP)
```

In Form I have something like,

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BusinessForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['business_group_choices'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(choices=BUSINESS_GROUP)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things I would change...

First, I try to avoid "magic strings" wherever I can. Instead of:

```
BUSINESS_GROUP = (
    ('MNC','Multinational'),
    ('INT','International (Export/Import)'),
    ('DOM','Domestic/National'),
    ('LOC','Local'),
    ('VIR','Virtual'),
)
```

I would do:

```
#in my_app > constants.py
MNC = 0
INT = 1
DOM = 2
LOC = 3
VIR = 4

BUSINESS_GROUP_CHOICES = (
    (MNC, 'Multinational'),
    (INT, 'International (Export/Import)'),
    (DOM, 'Domestic/National'),
    (LOC, 'Local'),
    (VIR, 'Virtual'),
)
```

This necessitates a change in your model, and I've changed the field names to be a little clearer:

```
from django.db import models

from businesses.constants import BUSINESS_GROUP_CHOICES, MNC


class BusinessGroup(models.Model):
    business_group_type = models.IntegerField(choices=BUSINESS_GROUP_CHOICES,
        default=MNC)

    def __unicode__(self):
        choices_dict = dict(BUSINESS_GROUP_CHOICES)
        return choices_dict[self.business_group_type]


class Business(models.Model):
    business_groups = models.ManyToManyField(BusinessGroup)
```

The real problem is in your form. Instead of just re-defining the widget, you need to be using a ModelMultipleChoiceField, as such:

```
from django import forms

from businesses.models import BusinessGroup


class BusinessForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Business

    business_group = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=BusinessGroup.objects.all(),
                                                    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

That's why you were getting a primary key error. Your BUSINESS_GROUP is just a tuple. Django was trying to assign the value from the tuple from your choices as the primary key, which obviously it can't do. Instead, what the ModelMultipleChoiceField will do, is relate the *instance* of the BusinessGroup you selected to your Business.

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I really appreciate the input.

Comment: I think your solution is quite good, I realized after 2 days, finally mixed some of your ideas with mine. Great learning though thanks again

Comment: I think magic strings are waaaaay better than even more magical numbers. Let's say someone has to port the database to some other system. Which is easier to figure out -- that 4 corresponds to a constant `VIR` which corresponds to 'Virtual', or a record that actually has 'VIR' in the field itself? Actually, if you hate magical strings, you should create a model called BusinessGroupType. Can you offer a compelling reason why `1` is an intrinsically more valuable unit of data than `INT`?

Comment: Hi Jordan. I think you're right in that 1 doesn't have any more value than 'INT'. However, tuples can't be referenced by key, so 1 for 'INT' can serve a double purpose to retrieve the value. Creating a model for BusinessGroupType would be preferable in hindsight.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it right,
First thing first, never mix ManyToMany and choices, so my 2nd attempt was totally wrong. The problem was in form,

So Now final solution looks like,

```
BUSINESS_GROUP = (
    ('MNC','Multinational'),
    ('INT','International (Export/Import)'),
    ('DOM','Domestic/National'),
    ('LOC','Local'),
    ('VIR','Virtual'),
)

class BusinessGroup(models.Model):
    bgroup_type = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Business(models.Model):
    business_group_choices = models.ManyToManyField(BusinessGroup)
```

Rather than,

```
class BusinessForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BusinessForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['business_group_choices'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(choices=BUSINESS_GROUP)
```

In Form I have something like,

```
class BusinessForm(forms.ModelForm):
   business_group_choices = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label="Business Group", widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=BUSINESS_GROUP)
```

You need to use MultipleChoiceField with CheckboxSelectMultiple.

This one in the model is totally wrong(mixing M2M and choices),

```
class Business(models.Model):
    business_group_choices = models.ManyToManyField(BusinessGroup, verbose_name= "Business Group", choices=BUSINESS_GROUP)
```